# In Vim regex, Is there an abbreviation for the pattern dot followed by plus sign?

Tags: regular-expression

Given that the pattern `.\+` is frequently used, is there an abbreviated way of specifying it in Vim Regex?

Comment: If you preface your regex with `\v`, you don't have to escape that `+`.  e.g., `/\v.+`.  You can put this in your .vimrc file to always use it: `nnoremap / /\v`

Answer (score 1):

When you type `/` you're in command mode.  You can remap this by putting this in your .vimrc file:

```
cnoremap .+ .\+
```

This means, if you type `.+` in command mode, replace it with `.\+`.  You can replace the `.+` on the left with anything you want.

Comment: Thank you.  What is the significance of your first sentence? ("When you type / you're in command mode.")

Comment: @Sabuncu Well there are lots of mappings.  You can change what happens when you're in insert mode, normal mode, command mode, operator-pending mode, etc.  I expected that when you typed `/` you're in normal mode because you type the `/` in normal mode.  But I was surprised to learn that when you type `/` you're in command mode.  The same mode that you're in when you type `:`.  Therefore, you change this with a command mode mapping, not a normal mode mapping.  Type `:help map.txt` to learn more.

Comment: Could not get it to work.  I am using Vim 7.4 gvim on Windows 10.  I ran your cnoremap command in command mode (i.e. I did `:cnoremap...`).  Then tried using the mapping, and it did not work.

Comment: @Sabuncu odd.  I'm using vim on mac and it works for me.  Sorry, not sure why it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Also tried setting it in the vimrc, but same outcome.

Comment: Be warned: 1) this may add a delay when typing `.` when in command line mode 2) This will expand in other places e.g. `:grep '.+'`. This may not be as you want. Might be able to limit this via `cnoremap <expr> .+ getcmdtype() =~ '[/?]' ? '.\+' : '.+'`. 3) This could get award if you want to use very magic mode, e.g. `\v`

Comment: @DanielKaplan Can it be possible `inoremap \begin{document} \begin{document}<CR>\end{document}<Esc>O`?